# Why writing in kafka topic from spark rdd doesn't work

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

Why isn't the message written to kafka topic from the rdd. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. So basically I want to receive a message, do some filtering and write it to another kafka topic. How should I initialize the kafka producer withing the spark RDD?

PS: I want to do this with Kafka's own API and not with other api like cloudera's spark kafka writer.

```
JavaPairInputDStream<byte[], byte[]> directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, byte[].class,
            byte[].class, DefaultDecoder.class, DefaultDecoder.class, kafkaParams, topics);
    directKafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
        rdd.foreach(record -> {
            KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(kafkaProps);
            Schema.Parser parser = new Schema.Parser();
            Schema schema = parser.parse(USER_SCHEMA);
            DatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = new SpecificDatumReader<GenericRecord>(schema);
            Decoder decoderRec1 = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(record._1, null);
            Decoder decoderRec2 = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(record._2, null);
            GenericRecord messageValue = null;
            GenericRecord messageKey = null;
            try {
                messageValue = reader.read(null, decoderRec2);
                messageKey = reader.read(null, decoderRec1);
                ProducerRecord<String, String> record1 = new ProducerRecord<>("outputTopic", "myKey",
                        "Key: " + messageKey + " Value" + messageValue.toString());
                Future<RecordMetadata> sent = producer.send(record1);
                sent.get();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Received: " + messageValue + " and key: " + messageKey);
            producer.close();
        });
    });
    ssc.start();
    ssc.awaitTermination();
```

Here is the working example

```
JavaDStream<InputMessage> inputMessageStream = directKafkaStream.map(avroRecord -> InputMessageTranslator.decodeAvro(avroRecord._2));
    inputMessageStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
        rdd.foreach(message -> {
            KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(kafkaProps);
            ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>(startProps.getProperty(InputPropertyKey.OUTPUT_TOPIC.toString()),
                    "myKey", "" + message.getSessionStartTime());
            producer.send(record);
            producer.close();
        });
    });
```

Comment: error message?  actual output?  Where/when is the connection to kafka configured and executed?

Comment: Sorry for the late respone. There is no error message. The problem was, nothing was written to kafka topic but I figured it out. The kafka producer should be in the rdd. I added the working example.